# Orthogonality of Row Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

I want to prove the following theorem and I need some help for the last part of the proof.

> **Theorem**. Suppose that $A_{p\times n}$ and $B_{q\times n}$ are two rectangular matrices of ranks $p$ and $q$ with $p+q=n$. Let $A^{*}=\Big[E_{p\times p}\Big|\tilde{A}_{p\times q}\Big]_{p\times n}$ and $B^{*}=\Big[\tilde{B}_{q\times p}\Big|E_{q\times q}\Big]_{q\times n}$ be the row reduced echelon forms of $A$ and $B$ respectively , where $E_{r\times r}$ is the identity matrix with $r$ rows and columns. Then we have
>   \begin{align}
> &AB^T=0\quad && \iff \\
> &A^{*}B^{*T}=0 && \iff \\
> &\tilde{A}+\tilde{B}^T=0\quad && \iff \\
> &\det A^{*}_{i_1\dots i_p}=\det B^{*}_{k_1\dots k_q} && \text{for every $i_1\dots i_pk_1\dots k_q$ that is an even permutation of $1\dots n$,}
> \end{align}
>   where $A^{*}_{i_1\dots i_p}$ is a $p\times p$ matrix formed by $i_1\dots i_p$ columns of $A^{*}$ and $B_{k_1\dots k_q}$ is a $q\times q$ matrix formed by $k_1\dots k_q$ columns of $B^{*}$.

**My Thought**

The first two equivalences are easy to show. Indeed, since the row operations do not change the row space the first equivalence is followed. More rigorously, there exist two non-singular matrices $R_{p\times p}$ and $S_{q\times q}$ such that $RA=A^{*}$ and $SB=B^{*}$. Then we observe that
$$A^{*}B^{*T}=(RA)(SB)^T=(RA)(B^TS^T)=R(AB^T)S^T\quad\iff R^{-1}(A^{*}B^{*T})S^{-T}=AB^T.$$
Then a simple block multiplication of matrices $A^{*}$ and $B^{*T}$ shows that
$$A^{*}B^{*T}=E_{p\times p}\tilde{B}^T+\tilde{A}E_{q\times q}=\tilde{B}^T+\tilde{A}=\tilde{A}+\tilde{B}^T,$$
so the second equivalence follows. Let $\tilde{A}=[\tilde{a}_{ik}]$, $\tilde{B}=[\tilde{b}_{ki}]$ with $i=1,\dots,p$ and $k=1,\dots,q$. Then for the last equivalence, we should show that
\begin{align*}
&\tilde{a}_{ik}=-\tilde{b}_{ki}\quad\iff \\
&\det A^{*}_{i_1\dots i_p}=\det B^{*}_{k_1\dots k_q}\text{for every $i_1\dots i_pk_1\dots k_q$ that is an even permutation of $1\dots n$.}
\end{align*}
Comparing both sides of equations gives some clues. Can we have $\tilde{a}_{ik}=\det A^{*}_{i_1\dots i_p}$ and $-\tilde{b}_{ki}=\det B^{*}_{k_1\dots k_q}$ for some permutation $i_1\dots i_p k_1\dots k_q$?
If *Yes* then the backward implication is proved. I don't have any idea for the forward implication. I think this is more a combinatoric question to prove the last equivalence.

Any help or hint is appreciated. :)